# vtkplanesource set normal and quaternion

Tags: vtk

I already wrote code to create plane using vtkplanesource

```
std::vector<vtkPlaneSource*>planeList;
    for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
{

vtkPlaneSource *plane=vtkPlaneSource::New();
planeList.push_back(plane);


    //translates the center of the plane to the specified center point.
    planeList[i]->SetCenter(posx[i],posy[i],posz[i]);
     //to rotate the plane around the center of the plane, aligning the plane normal with the specified normal
    planeList[i]->SetNormal(70,180.0,0);
    }
```

I have quaternion txt file like this: 
img17.bmp = pos:-10.40 -13.48 -66.80  ori:1.17 -0.01 0.09 -0.98
img18.bmp = pos:-10.47 -13.96 -69.68  ori:1.19 -0.01 0.09 -0.98
img19.bmp = pos:-10.61 -13.89 -71.70  ori:1.31 -0.03 0.07 -0.95

txt file have orientation and orientation in quaternion. I study that set normal vtkplanesource will rotate plane, so I want used quaternion to rotate plane by using setnormal function. So, the set normal function on vtkplanesource with cooperate with quaternion, I need convert to euler angle, axis angle or what value? 
Any one can provide hints to me?

Answer (score 0):

What does a plane with 0 X/Y/Z rotation look like? A Normal of (0,0,1) or (0,1,0) most likely (depending on what conventions you're using).

Then you want to rotate it? Just rotate the normal by the quaternion.

Note: Your quaternion values may not be what you expect. It's typical for quaternions to be unit length,

Comment: By set normal , i need convert quaternion to euler angle or not .if convert to euler angle , my value should put radian or degree?

Comment: quaternion have 4 components, if I using it to set normal , I need normalise 1'and assign that value to normal ?

Comment: What I mean is that if you have a plane which, when there's 0 rotation on all axes, lies in the X,Y plane, then it has normal (0,0,1). Quaternions represent a rotation, so rotate (0,0,1) by the quaternion. ie. calculate q*normal*Inverse(q) and use that value to set the normal to your plane

Comment: Example, I have quaternion value ,1.17  0.01 0.09 0.98then I set normal  using -0.01-0.09,-0.98like this ?